# Look up specific word in a table array and return adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I would like to know if there is a way to use the `Vlookup` function to find specific words in a table array.

E.g
Table array:

```
Code: R2   Color: Blue 
Code: R3   Color: Red
```

- Code :EC-R2-01-2016, Color :Function should return Blue
- Code :EC-R3-04-2016, Color: Function should return Red

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with `VLOOKUP`, just combine it with `MID`:
`=VLOOKUP(MID(D2,4,2),A:B,2,FALSE)`

[image]